# Accessing database value with twig

Tags: php, html, arrays, twig

Currently in in my php I have this:

```
$vals['followers'][] =  R::find('follow', 'following_id=?', array($_GET['id']));
```

I get a return of all followers in the "follow" table with a following_id of the id in the URL. The "follow" table consists of the following columns:

-id

-user_id

-following_id

I want to pull the 'firstname' of the user with an 'id' the same as the value of 'user_id'('user' table is joint with 'follow' table via user_id). For example if I write this:

```
 {%for follow in followers %}{{follow.user_id}}{%endfor%}
```

I want to add something to show the 'firstname' of the user such as:

```
{{follow.user_id}}->firstname
```

I know the above code is not valid but I hope it shows what I am trying to do. 
Please let me know if this doesn't make sense and I will try explain again.

Thank you so much in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To take your words, this *does not make sense* in an MVC architecture (if you're using Twig, I assume you wish to design your application this way).

You should prepare what you want to display **before** rendering your view. So consider that `$vals['followers'][] = R::find('follow', 'following_id=?', array($_GET['id']));` is a first step, and then you iterate `$vals['followers']` (still in your controller) to complete the information you need to display.

Always remember that your view should display things, not recovering or calculating stuffs.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Ninsuo
Do you have any idea how I would then get the information on the correct user to display next to the follower info?
As I only have the user_id I can only display the id number and not the name of that user.

Comment: Query your database, just like what you did with the line `R::find('follow', 'following_id=?', array($_GET['id']));` but with your user entity. Guess: `$users = array(); foreach ($vals['followers'] as $follow) { $users[] = R::find('user', 'user_id=?', array($follow['user_id'])); }`.

Comment: Yup I am able to do that and I have found all associated users. The problem is in the display of it. I want it to say: `{{user.username}} followed user with id {{follow.following_id}}` but when I include `{%for follow in followers %}` and `{%for user in users %}` (depending on which is inside which) I get repeating values. For Example _andrewandrew followed user with id 10_

Comment: I developped a simple `array_join` function to simulate an SQL `INNER JOIN`. Enjoy: http://pastebin.com/tPpgJwDW

Comment: Thank you! I will have a look at this soon and get back to you